# Checkbox with background image

Tags: android

I need a control in Android view which acts like a button but also has a background image. I.e. I want to change the control background shape based on "selected" state. Things I've tried so far:

1. Create a custom background for CheckBox. I can assign a shape and selector to change the border color to my style which works great. When I try to set Checkbox button drawable it won't center or size to what I want and always stuck in it's own position.
2. Create a layer-list with bitmap and checkbox borders - this works brilliant, however I can't change the bitmap source in runtime (or I don't know how), especially when I have state selectors in background xml. Every button has a different bitmap background in my case.

This is doing my head for the latest few days. Please help.